# How to get Highlighting response for all fields with SolR

Tags: lucene, solr, highlighting, solrj

hi all:
    I have a document with two fields, name and text, the content of them are same.
    but when I use highlighting query, the response only return one field which is in parameter q.
    
eg:
htp://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select/?q=name:sony&hl=true&hl.fl=name,text
this only return name in highlighting response
htp://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select/?q=text:sony&hl=true&hl.fl=name,text
this only return text in highlighting response

I want to get all field with highlighting, is the hl.fl useless?
thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should work.  The one thing that stands out to me is the name of the other field you have is 'text'    I would try changing the name of that field and try this again.  That just looks like a word you might not want to use cause it could be reserved somewhere along the lines.

Can you do a q=text:sony

?

Does it give the same result?

Comment: text is not reserved. its the default search field in solr. and normally a lot of fields are copied into this. @Illu: so maybe somewhere is a copyField directive (schema.xml) which copies 'name' into 'text' and messed up sth?